# Dynamic placement of tooltip based on viewport size does not work Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am using the tooltip functionality of Bootstrap 3. In the documentation, it says I can call

> placement: 'auto'

in my initialisation of the tooltip and so I have done the following:

```
$(".tour-badges li img, .difficulty-rating li").tooltip({ container: 'body', placement: 'auto' });
```

This should prevent the tooltip from appearing outside of the viewport. So, if a user views the site on a mobile and they scroll so the tooltip trigger is at the top of the screen, the tootip should appear below because the available screenspace is automatically calculated. However, this does not work.

Does anyone know how I can fix this:

[image]

So that instead it does this and moves to where there is available space in the viewport:

[image]

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.

N.B.

I tried using the following code to fix this issue but this makes the tooltip always appear below the content which is not what I want.

```
var test = {
        placement: function (context, source) {
            var position = $(source).position();

            if (position.top < 110) {
                return "bottom";
            }

            return top;
        }
    }

    $(".tour-badges li img, .difficulty-rating li").tooltip(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Bootstrap 3 documentation:

> How to position the tooltip - top | bottom | left | right | auto.
>   When "auto" is specified, it will dynamically reorient the tooltip. For example, if placement is "auto left", the tooltip will display to the left when possible, otherwise it will display right.

Try to use `placement: 'auto top'`

Comment: This does not work. As I have already mentioned above the use of placement auto or even placement auto top does not work. The tooltip simply extends above the fold.